# Como conjugar los SELECT para ocultar sus OPTIONS en HTML

Tags: php, html

mi consulta es la siguiente, tengo una base de datos de tabla "departamentos" que presenta las siguientes columnas: departamento, provincia, distrito. con esto hago un llamado a la base de datos para poder brindarle opciones a los 3 SELECT que presento. entonces lo que yo busco es que los select conjuguen entre si, osea que este desbloqueado departamento y que este bloqueado provincia y distrito. entonces cuando seleccione un departamento, se desbloquee provincia, y que solo me muestre las provincias de ese departamento, y lo mismo cuando seleccione provincia, me muestre los distritos de esa provincia.

algo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y el codigo es el siguiente:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>SELECT</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<center>
<label>Departamento: </label>
<select name="sss" id="sss" onchange="this.form.submit()">
  <option value="">Seleccione una opcion</option>
       <?php
      $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
      mysql_select_db("informacion",$con);
      mysql_set_charset("utf8",$con);
      $consulta1= mysql_query("SELECT distinct(departamento) as x FROM departamentos "); 
          while($data= mysql_fetch_array($consulta1)){
                     $depa=$data['x'];
                     echo "<option value='".$depa."' $selected>".$depa."</option>"; 
                    }
         ?>
    </select>
   <br><br>
   <label>Provincia: </label>
   <select name="ttt" id="ttt" onchange="this.form.submit()">
       <option value="">Seleccione una opcion</option>
       <?php
      $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
      mysql_select_db("informacion",$con);
      mysql_set_charset("utf8",$con);
      $consulta2= mysql_query("SELECT distinct(provincia) as x FROM departamentos where departamento='LIMA'"); 
          while($data= mysql_fetch_array($consulta2)){
                     $provi=$data['x'];
                     echo "<option value='".$provi."' $selected>".$provi."</option>"; 
                    }
         ?>
   </select>
   <br><br>
    <label>Distrito: </label>
   <select name="vvv" id="vvv">
   <option value="">Seleccione una opcion</option>
       <?php
      $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
      mysql_select_db("informacion",$con);
      mysql_set_charset("utf8",$con);
      $consulta3= mysql_query("SELECT distinct(distrito) as x FROM departamentos where departamento='LIMA' AND provincia='LIMA'"); 
          while($data= mysql_fetch_array($consulta3)){
                     $distr=$data['x'];
                     echo "<option value='".$distr."' $selected>".$distr."</option>"; 
                    }
         ?>

       </select>
       </center>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Se podra hacer la conjugacion? Es necesario hacer con SELECT o se puede hacer de otra manera?

Comment: A mi se me ocurre lo siguiente: Que cuando se seleccione un combo, cambie el estado del otro. Si te gusta esta idea te la desarrollo.

Answer (score 0):

Se me ha ocurrido algo así. Lo que hago es dejar el segundo select por defecto desabilitado y cuando cambia el estado del select le quito la propiedad de deshabilitado.

He utilizado la librería JQuery, es por si lo quieres utilizar en tus archivos (aunque para la prueba he utilizado una [ruta online](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js)).

Por último, aclarar que los datos los he puesto yo a mano (para que fuese un ejemplo sencillo).

```html
    <html>
        <body>
            A:<select type="text" name="uno" id="uno">
                <option selected="true" disabled="disabled" value='1'>Seleccione una opción</option>
                <option value='2'>Casa</option>
                <option value='3'>Perro</option>
            </select>
            <br>
            B: <select type="text" name="dos" id="dos" disabled="">
                <option selected="true" disabled="disabled" value='1'>Seleccione una opción</option>
                <option value='2'>Luis</option>
                <option value='3'>Jaime</option>
            </select>
        </body>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#uno').change(function () {
                    $('#dos').removeAttr('disabled');
                });
            });
        </script>
    </html>
```